# Why when mousedown left key or right key the code not work in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, jquery-events, mousedown

html code:

```
<div class="wrap">
</div>
```

js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("body").mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 1:
            alert('hello!');
            break;
        case 2:
            alert('forbid the key');
            break;
        default:
            alert('hehhe');
    }
});
```

When I open the page then press the left mouse key, it doesn't alert hello. why?

When I press the right key, I want to `alert("forbid the left")`, then after two minutes then close the page. How to add the function to the case 2.

ps: this is I want to learn how to use left key and right key using js

Comment: Firstly, `3` is a right click. Secondly, you will not want to do that. That kind of thing does not increase security and only serves to make users hate your site.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté He may be trying to create a custom right click menu

Comment: @CodyGuldner good point. I still dislike it for most uses, though it can be useful sometimes.

Comment: Yeah. I think it could cause some errors if this turned out to be a huge website. But it is most likely a small website that nobody will get upset over

Answer (score 3):

### `mousedown` event

It works after a little fiddling.

- You were missing `});` at the end of your script.
- `.wrap` was taking up no space to begin with, I set its `height` so it would.
- You had the button numbers wrong - Left = 1, Middle = 2, Right = 3.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radpt/)

**CSS**

```
html, body, .wrap {
    height:100%;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".wrap").mousedown(function (event) {
        switch (event.which) {
            case 1:
                alert('left button');
                break;
            case 2:
                alert('middle button');
                break;
            default:
                alert('right button');
        }
    });
});
```

### Closing the window

You would close the window after a certain period by calling `window.close()` (or simply `close()`) from `setTimeout()`

```
// Call close after 120000ms
setTimeout(close, 120000);
```

### Thoughts

I have to agree with Fabrício Matté and doing this sort of thing is very bad practice. You will annoy your users by doing these unexpected things and disabling normal functionality. I'm of the opinion that only games/similar should ever override the right-click event.

Comment: how to auto close the page after 2 minutes when pop the window,

Comment: add a function after alert('right button'); but i don't know how to do? i test the code setTimeout('funA()', 2000);funA(){$(".wrap").hide()}

Comment: i put the setTimeout(close, 120000); after  alert('left button'); when i click the mouse left key. then after 2minutes. the page not closed. thank u

Comment: Try it without the quotes or parentheses on `funA` like so: `setTimeout(funA, 2000); funA() { $(".wrap").hide(); }`

Comment: To close the page you pass the `window.close` function or simply `close` in to `setTimeout` as stated above. `setTimeout(close, 120000);`

Comment: when i click the mouse left key.it will alert a window, then after 2 minutes. i want to close the page, am i right?setTimeout(close, 120000); put this line after alert('left button');

Comment: Yep, I just double checked to make sure, `setTimeout(close, 120000);` will work, putting it after `alert('left button');` will start the countdown from the moment OK is pressed on the alert box.